# Agree to the Microsoft Symbol Server dialog

Tags: debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

Various debuggers with support for the Microsoft Symbol Server display a dialog with terms of use for the service upon first invocation.

How to get rid of it?

And yes, I maintain that debugging is an inherent part of *programming **and** software development* which is why this question is **not off topic**. Using the symsrv.dll in Windows is an inherent part of debugging and therefore it clearly relates *to programming or software development*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get rid of the dialog, you should create an empty file or directory named `symsrv.yes` in the folder that contains the `symsrv.dll`, the component responsible for displaying the dialog and providing the connectivity to the service.

**Note:** there can be several instances of the DLL all over your hard drive, depending on whether the debugger you are using comes with its own copy.

**Also note:** it is also possible to decline the terms by placing a file named `symsrv.no` instead. If both files exist, `symsrv.yes` will take precedence.

Comment: How did you find out about this trick, running Procmon?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: actually accidentally through my IDA Pro installation, where I must have created the file myself in 2010 but forgot about it. Now in another debugger it bugged me and I remembered the file and set out to find what this is all about. IDA was of help, too *cough* *cough*